# Sampling a specific number of points from a Weibull distribution in Python

Tags: python, scipy, montecarlo, weibull

I have a dataset (the diameters of ~1,000 trees) from which I have derived a mean tree diameter (21.6”) and standard deviation (12.4”). My analysis suggests these data are from a Weibull distribution (numpy.random.weibull).

I would like to run Monte Carlo simulations to generate a series of hypothetical forests that follow this data distribution -- that is, to extrapolate my data from 1,000 trees to an 80,000 tree forest of diameters sampled from my Weibull distribution.

To accomplish this, in Python I would like to:

1. **Create a Weibull distribution** with the mean and standard deviation of my dataset
2. **Sample from this distribution** 20 times to create these hypothetical forest size distributions, where each forest has ~80,000 points
3. **Export these tables into Excel** (I presume) in order to use this information to calculate forest biomass and carbon storage based on diameter

I am a complete beginner in both stats and Python, and am struggling from the scipy documentation how to incorporate my mean and std deviation into generation of the Weibull distribution as well as how to sample from the distribution once it's been created in a way that is exportable.

Many apologies in advance for any errors or ambiguities in framing the question -- the learning curve for coding and stats sure is steep!

Comment: You don't specify a Weibull distribution using mean and variance (like you would for a Gaussian). Take a look at this link: [Weibull distribution: from mean and variance to shape and scale factor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769765/weibull-distribution-from-mean-and-variance-to-shape-and-scale-factor)

Comment: Yikes, thanks for that reality check. I think that may be above my skill level for now, particularly without comparable for Python (vs. Matlab). Maybe putting the Weibull part aside for a second: any insights into how to sample from a different distribution (eg lognormal)?

Comment: Do you have the original data, or just the mean and std. dev.?

Comment: I have the original data, from which I derived mean and std. dev. in JMP.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but if anyone comes across it you can convert the mean and standard deviation of a dataset to the parameters of a Weibull distribution.

Good answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159452/how-can-i-recreate-a-weibull-distribution-given-mean-and-standard-deviation-and) on how to do it.

We can implement this in python

```py
mu = 21.6
std = 12.4

k = (std/mu)**(-1.086)
lambda_ = mu / (gamma(1 + 1./k))
k, lambda_
```

```
(1.8270937149009134, 24.30584398186227)
```

You can then simulate the 80,000 new values with numpy. You can  save it to a csv which can be opened in Excel with pandas.

```py
from numpy.random import weibull
import pandas as pd


synthetic_samples = lambda_ * weibull(k, 80_000)
pd.DataFrame(synthetic_samples).to_csv('new_forest.csv')
```